# Problem with building jhbuild

Tags: 14.04, pygtk, jhbuild

I'm new to Linux. I need to install Python gtk+ 3. Before that I'm supposed to install and build jhbuild. I installed most of the dependencies manually, since it was throwing errors. I currently get this error when I give the command `jhbuild build`.

```
W: Circular dependencies detected: meta-gnome-core -> meta-gnome-core-shell -> dconf -> glib -> gvfs -> glib
W: Circular dependencies detected: meta-gnome-core -> meta-gnome-core-shell -> dconf -> glib -> glib-networking -> glib
W: Circular dependencies detected: meta-gnome-core -> meta-gnome-core-shell -> dconf -> glib -> dconf
W: Circular dependencies detected: meta-gnome-core -> meta-gnome-core-shell -> evolution-data-server -> gtk+ -> adwaita-icon-theme -> gtk+
W: gnome-control-center has a dependency on unknown "network-manager-applet" module
W: gnome-control-center has a dependency on unknown "network-manager-applet" module
Required packages:
  System installed packages which are too old:
    plymouth (ply-boot-client.pc, required=0.8.9, installed=0.8.8)
    gnutls (gnutls.pc, required=3.1, installed=2.12.23)
    libsystemd-daemon (libsystemd-daemon.pc, required=210, installed=204)
    libsystemd-login (libsystemd-login.pc, required=210, installed=204)
  No matching system package installed:
    libsystemd (libsystemd.pc, required=210)
jhbuild build: Required system dependencies not installed. Install using the command 'jhbuild sysdeps --install' or to ignore system dependencies use command-line option --nodeps
```

What should I do? Also, if there is a better way to install Python GTK+ 3, then please give suggestions in that regard as well.

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and behind a college proxy.

Answer (score 0):

As you said

> I'm new to Linux

the answer is simple: Forget it.

Trusty is to old to build the latest GNOME/GTK3 release with `jhbuild`. Therefore upgrade to the latest Ubuntu release. You *could* compile each version yourself. But trust me, that's the wrong way for you.

---

```
System installed packages which are too old:
    plymouth (ply-boot-client.pc, required=0.8.9, installed=0.8.8)
    gnutls (gnutls.pc, required=3.1, installed=2.12.23)
    libsystemd-daemon (libsystemd-daemon.pc, required=210, installed=204)
    libsystemd-login (libsystemd-login.pc, required=210, installed=204)
```

You need newer development libraries. In this case, you have to compile it yourself as your are on Trusty.

```
No matching system package installed:
    libsystemd (libsystemd.pc, required=210)
```

The library `libsystemd-dev` isn't available for Trusty. Goto the developer page, download the source code and compile it yourself.

Comment: So, what do i do for libsystemd-dev?

Comment: As I said in my answer. Forget it or upgrade to 15.04.